# UICollectionViewCell with three UICollectionViews using Compositional Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to accomplish a dynamic cell with the new collection view compositional layout

basically this is what I have:

- UICollectionView (Compositional Layout)

  - UICollectionViewCell

    - innerStackView (Vertical UIStack ) // Contains postDescription and 'from Riyadh' Label
    - ....
    - UICollectionView (Compositional Layout)
    - UICollectionView (Flow Layout -Horizontal)
    - UICollectionView(Compositional Layout)

**I have tried two approaches:**

1- Adding the inner collection views inside a vertical stack,

2- Adding the inner collection views inside the container view with constraints

This is what I have currently:

**The top UICollectionView (Compositional Layout)**

```
func setupCollectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(1),
        heightDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(300)
    )
    
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1)
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = .zero
    section.interGroupSpacing = 0
    
    let headerFooterSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.3)
    )
    
    let sectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
        layoutSize: headerFooterSize,
        elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
        alignment: .top
    )
            
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionHeader]
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}
```

**The Cell (Using Container View Constraints)**

```
class FeedsCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var innerStackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var postDescription: UILabel!

var imageGalleryCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var reactionCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var commentCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func with(viewModel: FeedsCellViewModel) -> Self {
    postDescription.text = ".random(in: 0...255)"
            
    if !viewModel.imageProvider.dataSource.isEmpty {
        let imageLayout = setupImageLayout()
        
        imageGalleryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: imageLayout)
        imageGalleryCollectionView.delegate = viewModel.imageProvider
        imageGalleryCollectionView.dataSource = viewModel.imageProvider
        
        containerView.addSubview(imageGalleryCollectionView)
        
    }
    
    if !viewModel.reactionProvider.dataSource.isEmpty {
        let reactionLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        reactionLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        reactionCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: reactionLayout)
        reactionCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        reactionCollectionView.dataSource = viewModel.reactionProvider
        reactionCollectionView.delegate = viewModel.reactionProvider
        
        innerStackView.addArrangedSubview(reactionCollectionView)
        
        reactionCollectionView.anchor(heightConstant: 32)
    }
    
    if !viewModel.commentProvider.dataSource.isEmpty {
        let commentLayout = setupCommentLayout()
        
        commentCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: commentLayout)
        commentCollectionView.dataSource = viewModel.commentProvider
        commentCollectionView.delegate = viewModel.commentProvider
        
        containerView.addSubview(commentCollectionView)

        imageGalleryCollectionView.anchor(top: innerStackView.bottomAnchor, left: innerStackView.leftAnchor, bottom: commentCollectionView.topAnchor, right: innerStackView.rightAnchor)

        commentCollectionView.anchor(top: imageGalleryCollectionView.bottomAnchor, left: innerStackView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: innerStackView.rightAnchor)
                    
    }

    return self
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageGalleryCollectionView?.removeFromSuperview()
    reactionCollectionView?.removeFromSuperview()
    commentCollectionView?.removeFromSuperview()
}

func setupCommentLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: .init(appearance: .insetGrouped))
    return layout
}

func setupImageLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let mainItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
      layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(2/3),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))

    mainItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
      top: 2,
      leading: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      trailing: 2)

    let pairItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
      layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5)))

    pairItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
      top: 2,
      leading: 2,
      bottom: 0,
      trailing: 2)

    let trailingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
      layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
      subitem: pairItem,
      count: 2)

    let mainWithPairGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
      layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(4/9)),
      subitems: [mainItem, trailingGroup])

    let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
      layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0)),
      subitems: [
        mainWithPairGroup,
      ]
    )

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: nestedGroup)
    
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    
}
  }
```

## The Result

---

**The Cell (using UIStackView)**

```
func with(viewModel: FeedsCellViewModel) -> Self {
    postDescription.text = ".random(in: 0...255)"
            
    if !viewModel.imageProvider.dataSource.isEmpty {
        let imageLayout = setupImageLayout()
        
        imageGalleryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: imageLayout)
        imageGalleryCollectionView.delegate = viewModel.imageProvider
        imageGalleryCollectionView.dataSource = viewModel.imageProvider
        
        innerStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageGalleryCollectionView)
        
    }
    
    if !viewModel.reactionProvider.dataSource.isEmpty {
        let reactionLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        reactionLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        reactionCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: reactionLayout)
        reactionCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        reactionCollectionView.dataSource = viewModel.reactionProvider
        reactionCollectionView.delegate = viewModel.reactionProvider
        
        innerStackView.addArrangedSubview(reactionCollectionView)
        
        reactionCollectionView.anchor(heightConstant: 32)
    }
    
    if !viewModel.commentProvider.dataSource.isEmpty {
        let commentLayout = setupCommentLayout()
        
        commentCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: commentLayout)
        commentCollectionView.dataSource = viewModel.commentProvider
        commentCollectionView.delegate = viewModel.commentProvider
        
        innerStackView.addArrangedSubview(commentCollectionView)

    }

    return self
}
```

## The Result

---

It's really been a struggle, it's my 5th day trying to figure this out.

Comment: I am in a very similar situation.  I have made a collection view inside a collecitonview cell all with compositional layout.  The layout is ok, but the scrolling is choppy.